# Why pthread_join does not block and wait for the thread to finish?

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system, pthreads

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void* thread(void *v) {
    printf("The thread starts now\n");
    //pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {
    int tid1;
    int retValue = 0;
    pthread_create(&tid1, NULL,thread, NULL);

    retValue = pthread_join(tid1, NULL);
    printf("Thread ID: %d, return value: %d\n",tid1, retValue);

    retValue = pthread_join(tid1, NULL);
    printf("Thread ID: %d, return value: %d\n",tid1, retValue);
    return 0;
}
```

Sometimes the output is:

```sh
Thread ID: 1877241856, return value: 3
Thread ID: 1877241856, return value: 3
The thread starts now

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The question is：

1. By definition, `pthread_join` should block, wait for `thread` to finish executing, and then execute code that follows it. But why in my code, `thread` runs after the two `pthread_join` finish?
2. By definition, `pthread_join` returns 0 to indicate successful joining, but why the `retValue` of my code is always 3, whether `thread` runs before or after the `pthread_join` function?

Comment: What does the return value from `pthread_join` tell you?

Comment: Where are the compiler diagnostic messages from the compiler? Since it is incorrect it doesn't compile without diagnostics.

Comment: The compiler says " Format specifies type 'unsigned long' but the argument has type 'int' ". This is helpful but I didn't know I should read the diagnostic messages. Thanks @AnttiHaapala

Comment: @NameNull so, next time compile with `-Werror` so they will become errors. And maybe `-Wall` too... But I meant the *original* program without `pthread_t`, it would have said about incompatible pointer type to `pthread_create`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of bugs in this code:

1. The first argument of `pthread_create()` should be a `pthread_t`, not an `int`.  They are quite possibly not the same size, or otherwise interchangeable, so `tid1` might not be a valid pthread id.
2. The thread does not return 0, or any other value for that matter.  There is no `return` statement.
3. "On success, pthread_join() returns 0; on error, it returns an error number."
   The thread's return value, if there was one, would be placed into the unused 2nd argument of `pthread_join()`.  What is being treated as the return value is in fact the result of the `pthread_join()` call itself.  Which is an error.  Perhaps it is related to #1 above?

Comment: After setting `tid1` to be type `pthread_t`, the program now has expected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to those found by TrentP worst bug of all is

> Joining with a thread that has previously been joined results in undefined behavior.

i.e. calling `pthread_join` **twice** on the same thread

```
retValue = pthread_join(tid1, NULL);
retValue = pthread_join(tid1, NULL);
```

Is utterly wrong and saying it works if you change `tid1` to `pthread_t` is wrong. The behaviour being undefined means that anything can happen when `pthread_join` is called the second time - `pthread_join` can return an error, `pthread_join` can return success, it can crash, it can hang, it can modify some other parts of memory, it can cause a new thread to be started...

Comment: The second `retValue` statement is an experiment. I just wanted to know what would happen when I join a thread that has already been joined. Now the second `retValue` is 3, which is an error and is as expected.

Comment: @NameNull ok so you didn't read what I wrote. It is not expected. Because the behaviour is **undefined** you can expect **nothing at all**. You just **must not** call it twice.

Comment: @NameNull Please see [What is undefined behavior and how does it work?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277486)